# Can't get contracts info based on Android 2.1

Tags: android, android-emulator

I write an `Antivity` to retrieve contracts info based on Android 2.1:

```
package com.yarin.android.Examples_03_02;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Activity01 extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        String string = "";     
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        //得到ContentResolver对象
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();  
        //取得电话本中开始一项的光标
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        //向下移动一下光标
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) 
        { 
            //取得联系人名字
            int nameFieldColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);     
            String contact = cursor.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex); 
            //取得电话号码
            int numberFieldColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.NUMBER);    
            String number = cursor.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);

            string += (contact+":"+number+"\n");
        }
        cursor.close();
        //设置TextView显示的内容
        tv.setText(string);
        //显示到屏幕
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

After deploying the `.apk` onto emulator and starting up the activity, I got the following error:

```
12-20 12:51:27.183: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(951): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yarin.android.Examples_03_02/com.yarin.android.Examples_03_02.Activity01}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
        at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
        at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:135)
        at com.yarin.android.Examples_03_02.Activity01.onCreate(Activity01.java:30)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
        ... 11 more
```

which forced the app closed:
[image]

Comment: Why are you using PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME? What's the purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME use ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME .

please check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

{public void setPhoneNumber(Intent data){

```
       Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(data.getData(), null, null, null, null);      
       while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
       {           
           String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

          displayName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));

           String hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

           if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
               hasPhone = "true";
           else
               hasPhone = "false" ;

           if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
           {
            Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext()) 
            {
             contactNumberEdit.setText(phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
            }
            phones.close();
           }
      }  
       cursor.close();





}}
```

Comment: `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER` can't work. It can't find the phone number, WTF

Comment: make sure you have added some contacts on phone or emulator with the contact name and number, Please check the above working code

Answer (score 0):

```
{import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DEMOActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        String string = "";     
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();  

        Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        String contact=null,hasPhone=null,number=null;
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) 
        { 
            // To extract the _ID which is the unique field of the contacts table
            String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

            // to extract the name from the contact 
            int nameFieldColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);     
            contact = cursor.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex); 

            // this gives wether the contact has phone number or not 
            hasPhone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

            if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                hasPhone = "true";
            else
                hasPhone = "false" ;

            if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
            {

             Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
             while (phones.moveToNext()) 
             {
                // here we extract the contact of give contact ID
             number=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
             }
             phones.close();
            }

        string += (contact+":"+number+"\n");
        }
        cursor.close();

        tv.setText(string);

        setContentView(tv);



    }
}}
```